# Add new user with credentials Temporary property does not working

Tags: keycloak, identity

Keycloak REST API in UserRepresentation model there is a "credentials" property, which has ( type = "password", value="some", temporary=true/false } 
On adding new user I wonna force the user to change his password on the first login. I know that it can be done globally in Required Actions in Realm/Authorization options, but if "force changing password" is not setted as default. I thought to control it by the setup that property in user.credentials model, but looks like it's totally dummy property and not makes any effect, always works as false. Am I right ?

P.S. I also take a look at the model in https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b4b3527df7656bfaaee351ec414e56c683c134c2/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UserResource.java  I fond in resetPassword it's setted up, but not in updateUser ( which I assume is used for add user also ).

```
{
    "username": "New_User_3",
    "enabled": true,
    "firstName": "NewUserDemoFirst",
    "lastName": "NewUserDemoLast",
    "email": "New_User_3@mail.test",
    "attributes": {     
    },
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": false,
        "view": false,
        "mapRoles": false,
        "impersonate": false,
        "manage": false
    },
    "credentials": [
        {
            "type": "password",
            "temporary": true,
            "value": "xM0K+G"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try to create user in Keycloak Admin Console then set temporary credentials for this user and trace requests that Keycloak Admin UI sends to Keycloak backend when you perform this operations.

Answer (score 8):

You could add required actions to the JSON object as shown. This would force the user to update the password upon login for the first time.

```
 {
   "username": "userxyz",
   "credentials": [
     {
       "type": "password",
       "value": "passwordabc",
       "temporary": true
     }
   ],
   "requiredActions": [
     "UPDATE_PASSWORD"
   ],
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> but looks like it's totally dummy property and not makes any effect, always works as false. Am I right ?

Yes.

This seem to be a bug of Keycloak. I can reproduce it too.

To fix the bug, I think the following lines should be added to `org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.UserResource.updateUserFromRep()`:

```java
List<CredentialRepresentation> credentials = rep.getCredentials();
if (credentials != null) {
    for (CredentialRepresentation credential : credentials) {
        if (CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD.equals(credential.getType())
                 && credential.isTemporary() != null && credential.isTemporary()) {
            user.addRequiredAction(UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD);
        }
    }
}
```

A workaround is to call `reset-password` after creating a user.

PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password

See also:https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/7.0/rest-api/index.html

Comment: I have created JIRA ticket: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-11772.